# Play one movie right after another in XCode Objective-C for iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using a MPMoviePlayerViewController in an iOS Objective-C project and aim to play two movies right after each other in full screen, without any visible black flicker delay in-between the two playings. How would one go about this? Right now, when I run my code which is similar to http://www.devx.com/wireless/article/44642/1954 , there will be a small lag in-between the first and second movie, whereas the point of my potential game is that it should appear seamless and unnoticeable.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How is this related to Xcode?

Comment: I just mentioned the environment I'm working in for completeness sake (for instance, if part of the solution would be to press a certain button to include a certain framework, then it would relate to the IDE).

Answer (score 1):

the lag will always be there , the only thing that you can do is join the two movies together before playing them using the AVComposition class and then play them without any lag.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to "stop" at the last frame of the first movie, have it stand still, then load the second movie and immediately play it? I.e. there would be a delay, but there would be no "black screen flicker" between the two movies.

Comment: you can try it but I doubt as the lag I think is because of the video being loaded.